# Error with Python SDK for IBM Watson when importing into Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

The error I receive is:

> DeprecationWarning: watson-developer-cloud moved to ibm-watson. To get
> updates, use the new package.

```
  service = watson_developer_cloud.AssistantV1(
```

I have tried updating **watson-developer-cloud** using `pip install` however I still have the same error.

The code used is below. All done in Python. Just left out the API key from the original code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
service = watson_developer_cloud.AssistantV1(
    iam_apikey= '',
    version= '2021-01-20'



import os
from pathlib import Path

import slack
import ibm_watson
import ibm_cloud_sdk_core
import watson_developer_cloud
from ibm_watson import AssistantV1
from dotenv import load_dotenv
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for the [instructions on that Python package for IBM Watson services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk). It is like stated in the warning:

**watson-developer-cloud** is now named **ibm-watson**. What you have to do is

```
pip install ibm-watson
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade ibm-watson
```

Because the packagae is named **ibm-watson**, you would need to use that name for import...

```
import ibm-watson
```

or

```
from ibm_watson import AssistantV1
```

See the linked repository for examples.

Comment: Tried both install methods and still did not see any change in the error message.

Comment: You probably did not change the module name in your code, right? I added that explicitly above.

Comment: Provided an update on my edits showing the imports. Would there be a different edit to use for watson_developer_cloud seems to be the only edit which causes this error?

Comment: Do not use anything named watson_developer_cloud. It has been renamed to ibm_watson. Everything else can stay as is in your code.

Comment: Ahh simple mistake upon changing watson_developer_cloud to ibm_watson in my code it now works. Thanks for the help. Just a quick additional question if you know, the iam_apikey seems to provide an error stating unexpected keyword  argument. Would this like watson developer be different. This is an additional ask. No worries if you dont will accept the answer for the original question.